# Iframe and flash

Tags: flash, iframe

I googled this matter a lot, and maybe I am not googling right and I didnt find anything on stack also so I am wondering, is it possible to somehow disable flash from loading in an iframe? Or to turn it off after iframe loads?

Comment: Yes, is there any way to accomplish that?